# Next steps for android native library RE (JNI_OnLoad, root check)

Tags: android, ghidra, frida

I'm trying to RE an Android app that detects root on a system.
Using frida to backtrace 'access' calls I found out that the root check happens natively:

```
access(/system/xbin/su, 0x0)

Interceptor Backtrace: 0x7a9d8b12dc libnoncnliheopp.so!0x2a72dc
    0x7a9d8b12dc libnoncnliheopp.so!0x2a72dc
    0x7a9d8bd608 libnoncnliheopp.so!0x2b3608
    0x7a9d8bf29c libnoncnliheopp.so!0x2b529c
    0x7a9d7a66bc libnoncnliheopp.so!0x19c6bc
    0x7a9d9a7aa4 libnoncnliheopp.so!0x39daa4
    0x7a9d9aa1d0 libnoncnliheopp.so!JNI_OnLoad+0x24
    0x7ab198a17c libart.so!_ZN3art9JavaVMExt17LoadNativeLibraryEP7_JNIEnvRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEP8_jobjectP7_jclassPS9_+0xd18
    0x7aa7231170 libopenjdkjvm.so!JVM_NativeLoad+0x1a4
    0x70c16a28 boot.oat!0x81a28
    0x70c16a28 boot.oat!0x81a28

retval: 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I've looked into to the libnoncnliheopp.so and it looks scrambled, the address from the backtrace (0x2a72dc + ghidra base 0x100000) doesn't point to a function but something like a data block (see below). Since the app runs the root checks at startup it's difficult to hook it.

[image: Ghidra listing]

[Frida code](https://jsfiddle.net/p07zat6d/)

What's the best way to continue?

Comment: Are you sure the used base address included in the frida address is the same as used by Ghidra? Although frida is so nice to calculate the non-ASLR address there is still a base address included. I would first check if Ghidra uses the same base address (here called [image base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335254/150978)). If the so file is compressed/packed you could try to dump the library from memory

Comment: Oops.. Thank you. Updated. I dumped the memory right after getting the backtrace, but I don't see anything familiar.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmKcT.png